# LINQ to Entities query conversion

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a linq query like this:

```
from u in db.Users
where u.GetDisplayName().StartsWith(searchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
select u.MapToViewModel())
.ToList();
```

I don't have rich experience in linq, and I want to know whether this query causes performance degradation.

1. I doubt in where clause using `u.GetDisplayName().StartsWith(...)` does it successfully be converted to SQL?
2. And is `select u.MapToViewModel()` safe to perform such mapping?

Comment: A call to a method cannot be converted to SQL so no, that shouldn't work, only properties. But why didn't you run that and got the result?

Comment: You should try running the code and see if it works fine. For creating viewmodel you need to learn about automapper

Comment: yes, it works. But I doubt about performance. Does it make a single query to database and does 'where' clause is correctly converted to sql

Comment: You can run profiler on the database while executing this code and check what query is being generated. The measurements of performance depends on many things apart from query such as number of rows in table, network latency, load on the database, indexes on the table etc.

Comment: okey, seems I understood. Custom methods (`u.GetDisplayName()`) should not be used in where clause, so linq doesn't know how to convert them, other methods like string .StartsWith() should be checked in profiler. Any model mapping after `select` operator is executed only after query result set is retrieved, so it's nothing worried about.